# How To Dynamically Add Events to Dynamically Created Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a small `ASP` web application which can be used to determine whether or not 2 users have been assigned the same seat number.

To display the results / functionality, I decided to go with an `asp:Table`, where each row has 2 buttons (one for each user).

The administrator can click either one of the buttons to clear that user's seat number value from the system.

Here is the code which builds the table cells:

**BuildDuplicateTable** (called in `Page_Load`)

```
private void BuildDuplicateTable(List<Duplicate> duplicates)
{
    foreach (var dup in duplicates)
    {
        var row = new TableRow();
        var user1cell = new TableCell();
        var seatcell = new TableCell();
        var user2cell = new TableCell();

        var button1 = new Button();
        button1.Text = $"{dup.UserOne.UserName}";
        var button1cell = new TableCell();
        button1cell.Controls.Add(button1);
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(Test);

        var button2 = new Button();
        button2.Text = $"{dup.UserTwo.UserName}";
        var button2cell = new TableCell();
        button2cell.Controls.Add(button2);
        button2.OnClientClick = "return true";
        button2.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            ActiveDirectory.ClearProperty(dup.UserTwo.UserName, "extensionAttribute2");
        };

        user1cell.Text = dup.UserOne.UserName;
        seatcell.Text = dup.UserOne.SeatNumber;
        user2cell.Text = dup.UserTwo.UserName;

        row.Cells.Add(button1cell);
        row.Cells.Add(seatcell);
        row.Cells.Add(button2cell);

        MyAspTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I click on any of the buttons, the page is simply refreshed, and the data is no longer displayed (as I am handling postback in `Page_Load`). My event handler never fires ... Notice that in the code above I left in 2 separate methods of attaching an event handler that I tried - neither of them works!

**Duplicate**

```
class Duplicate
{
    public UserSeatNumberRelationship UserOne;
    public UserSeatNumberRelationship UserTwo;

    public Duplicate(UserSeatNumberRelationship userone, UserSeatNumberRelationship usertwo)
    {
        UserOne = userone;
        UserTwo = usertwo;
    }
}
```

**UserSeatNumberRelationship**

```
class UserSeatNumberRelationship
{
    public string UserName;
    public string SeatNumber;

    public UserSeatNumberRelationship(string username, string seatnumber)
    {
        UserName = username;
        SeatNumber = seatnumber;
    }
}
```

**Page_Load**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack) return;
    DuplicateList = FindDuplicates();
    BuildDuplicateTable(DuplicateList);
}
```

**Test**

```
    protected void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveDirectory.ClearProperty(UserName, "extensionAttribute2");
    }
```

Comment: where are you calling `BuildDuplicateTable`?

Comment: I am calling that in `Page_Load`

Comment: put that inside `if(!IsPostBack) { BuildDuplicateTable(<<argument>>); }` to ensure the table is not recreated with every post back; Re-creating may lose previous context of controls

Comment: @techspider I posted my `Page_Load` method - I think it is equivalent isn't it?

Comment: try this `button1.Click += Test`; hoping your `Test` has syntax `void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @techspider That is a method that I already tried (I added my test code above for reference) - I really feel like that should work. ..

Comment: `button1.Click += new EventHandler(Test);` this never compiles in my VS; `button1.Click += Test` this does

Comment: @techspider I have tried both of those methods and they both give me the exact same result (refreshing the page as a postback - no event handler called)

Comment: try moving this line `button1cell.Controls.Add(button1);` after assigning event handler; I believe the control has to be added to UI after all properties to it are assigned

Comment: Did you try removing the line `if (Page.IsPostBack) return;`? Dynamic controls should be recreated on every postback.

Comment: it is true as long as the unique id is maintained while it is re-generated

Comment: @ConnorsFan That did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **ConnersFan** mentioned in the comments, this was being caused by my `PostBack` handler in `Page_Load`.

So after removing this line

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) return;
```

The event handlers work fine.